# AttributeError at has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django, django-models

AttributeError type object 'Data_Point ' has no attribute 'objects'plz check and correct me

> AttributeError at /
>   type object 'myProduction' has no attribute 'objects'

**model**":

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Production(models.Model):
   title=models.CharField(max_length=120)
   def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

**My Form**

```
from  django import forms
from.models import Production
class myProduction(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Production
        fields =['title'] 

class Raw_Pro(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
```

**My View**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .form import myProduction,Raw_Pro
def my_index(request):
    my_form=Raw_Pro()
    if request.method=='POST':
        my_form=Raw_Pro(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            myProduction.objects.create(my_form.cleaned_data)
        else:
             print(my_form.errors)
    context={"form":my_form}
    return render(request, "index.html",context)
```

Comment: Your `myProduction` is a *form*, not a model. Furthermore you should not use a `.create(..)` in the first place, use `my_form.save()` instead.

Comment: def my_index(request):
    my_form=Raw_Pro()
    if request.method=='POST':
        my_form=Raw_Pro(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            #print(my_form.cleaned_data)
            #myProduction.objects.create(my_form.cleaned_data)
            my_form.save()

Comment: plz check and correct me i am facing same problem

Comment: Why are you using two forms here?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Raw_Pro' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Can't you use `myProduction` form in your `my_index` view?

Comment: i am sending data to model from form field

Comment: @PramodPandey: you somehow define a `ModelForm` and a "raw" `Form`, but that does not make (much) sense.

Comment: @Sanip if i will not used myProduction then how to send dada to my database

Comment: @PramodPandey: why would you *not* use a model form here, this is a clear case where a model form is likely the most elegant solution. One only uses raw forms when you for example want to update two or more models, or when there are no related models (like a contact page that simply sends an email).

Comment: I asked to use myProduction form instead of Raw_Pro form. You can take a look at @WillemVanOnsem's answer. That is what I meant.

Comment: i am fowling this tut https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5mRW0jo-U4  , time:2:33

Comment: Having a look at the tutorial link, I can see that the tutor is using `Product.objects.create(**my_form.cleaned_data)`. Have you noticed it? Look at the `2:41:14` timing of the tutorial.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django. if you have script can you share me . this types of https://makitweb.com/auto-populate-dropdown-with-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 2):

You make some mistakes here:

1. `myProduction` here is your `ModelForm` (defined in `forms.py`), not your model (this is `Production`, defined in `models.py);
2. you here use `Raw_Pro` as form, which is not a `ModelForm`, which is likely not what you want to use;
3. in case of a successful form, you can use `mymodelform.save()` to create/edit the object; and
4. if the creation is successful, you should redirect to a page, for example the same page. By not doing so, a refresh of the user, would trigger a POST with the same parameters.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .form import myProduction

def my_index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_form = myProduction(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            my_form.save()
            return redirect(my_index)  # or somewhere else
    else:
        my_form = myProduction()
    context = {"form":my_form}
    return render(request, "index.html",context)
```

> **Note**: as specified by [**PEP-8** [Python-doc]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you should use camelcase starting with an **U**ppercase for class names. So you better rename your `myProduction` class to `MyProduction`, or much better `ProductionForm`, since then it is clear what that class is doing.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django. if you have script can you share me . this types of makitweb.com/auto-populate-dropdown-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: @PramodPandey: there is an article on SIBTC with exactly that name: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html but given the current state of the code, it is probably a bit *too high* for now.

Comment: this script this show complicated do have some simple script

Comment: #How to pass cuntry & city name from dictionary
Indian_States =[("AP","Andhra Pradesh"),("AR","Arunachal Pradesh"),("AS","Assam")]
US_states =[("AL","Alabama"),("AK","Alaska"),("AS","AmericanSamoa")]
#How to pass cuntry & city name from dictionary
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)